# adding user to database from textbox in web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to save a username to a database after clicking the `Add User` button but having trouble this is what i have:

```
 private void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new DocMgmtDataContext())
        {
            User user = new User()
            {
                FullName = (NewUserName.Text as User).ID
            };
            db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        UpdateUserLists();
    }
```

it is not liking the `as User` part.

**MY SOLUTION**

`FullName = NewUserName.Text,
ID = Guid.NewGuid()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewUserName.Text` is probably of type `String` and you're trying to cast it to a `User`. This will certainly not work.

Try this:

```
 FullName = NewUserName.Text
```

Comment: I noticed that after i made this change - it worked and the user was added successfully but when i went to add another user it gave me an error that i cannot add duplicate user (different names) but as i looked into the database i noticed the user i added has id value of 00000... and i think every user i am adding it is trying to assign 000000... as well.

Comment: If you want to autogenerate an ID for each user, make the ID column of the database table an [IDENTITY column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), assuming you're using SQL Server.

Comment: so making the change in the database is the only solution? i just want to make sure because i wasn't the one creating it and want to make sure to ask before making the proper changes

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 FullName = (NewUserName.Text as User).ID
```

To this

```
 FullName = NewUserName.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that from your `NewUserName Textbox` you want to get user `FullName` so change your code to this:

```
private void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new DocMgmtDataContext())
    {
         User user = new User()
         {
                FullName = NewUserName.Text //fix
         };
         db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
         db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```